# iPhone Address Book Programming: ABPersonSetImageData

Tags: iphone

Currently in iPhone SDK, doing

ABPersonSetImageData

to set an image for a person creates a distorted thumbnail if image's height != width (try it out yourself). Has anyone come up with a solution for this?

Below is what happens if I do ABPersonSetImageData using a 200x30 image.
http://qkpic.com/767fd

Answer (score 0):

Probably expected functionality. Just crop it to be a square.